# Where can I find unique templates for Presentation folders?

Tags: print-design, presentation-design, portfolio

I have to design a Presentation Folder Design and print it. I have never done one before, I googled a bit and found some templates with a great tutorial above them :

http://www.proactivepr.org/presentation-folder-printing.shtml

I am wondering if anyone knows of more unique PDF templates for presentation folders. I need the templates for the cut lines/curves (the lines the cutter follows to cut the folders shape, if you don't get what I mean watch the tutorial) part of the presentation folder, not the visual design.

Ah, and preferably free ones...

And if you have done one before(a presentation folder) please feel free to share any tips from the design process to the printing part...

Thank you!

Comment: "PDF templates" is a misnomer. You can't design in Acrobat. Do you mean something else in the Adobe Suite?

Comment: No, what I found was PDF files with the lines for the cutting part of the design, then you open the PDF in Illustrator, and simply copy paste the cut lines from Illustrator to In Design.... but maybe it shouldn't be only PDF's, just templates... if you take a look at the tutorial I gave as an example you'll understand

Comment: I'll probably do one from strach... but Im sure I'll run into problems when I go to the printers... I never designed something that requierd custom cutting and folding...

Comment: @Lauren - "PDF templates" seems fine to me, if they originate in Illustrator they can be edited in Illustrator.

Comment: @Alan Gilbertson so... how come this question came up again in the "active" zone of the questions, I asked it sep 2011... its been a while, i don't see anything new to it... in the "active" area I see there's suppose to be something modified by John Davis, but I don't see anything... is it because his website is printingblue.com/folder-printing/custom-folder-printing.asp  ?  ...just curios

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resource request

Answer (score 2):

Follow e100's advice. Here's why: you have (or your client has) a budget, and the difference between the cost of a standard job and a custom job is substantial.

The cut lines in a template are called die lines. They are your guides to where the cuts will be made. Your folder will be made from card stock which will be cut after it's printed using a cutting die, then folded and glued.

Any commercial printer that does this kind of work has existing dies which he uses over and over again, so the cost of making them can be recovered a small bit at a time (amortized) across many jobs.

If you invent your own shapes, or use someone else's template with die lines that don't match what your printer already has, he must get a custom die made just for your job *and he is going to pass on the full cost to you*, perhaps with an added markup. Unless you have a very good reason and can afford the extra cost, then, it is better to pick your printer and use their template.

Always, always, always consult your printer any time you're doing something you haven't tackled before. The printer wants to do a good job. His reputation depends on it, after all. He will be happy that you asked, and happy to give you the help you need to get the best product for your client. Happy clients bring you more work, and tell their friends. That's the surest way to grow your business.

Answer (score 1):

Ask your printers first, they should have tried and tested cutting guides which you can use or adapt. Adapting will probably cost you more, as the printers will have to make a new physical cutting plate up.

You are looking for trouble by designing one from scratch with no experience, especially if it's anything at all complex (like pockets). There are subtle issues dependent on thickness of card used and gluing method which can trip you up.

If you definitely want to create your own template, you should get your printers to make up a dummy in plain card for approval before printing.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, this site offers a ton of die cut folder templates as well as print-ready design templates for presentation folders. If you need psd mockup templates, they have those too. http://www.companyfolders.com/design/die-cut-folder-templates